# NFS time out (mount) with vagrant & puphet

Tags: vagrant, nfs, puphpet

I've some trouble with mounting folder using Vagrant & Puphpet.

This is the error message (with --debug) :

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 INFO interface: error: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp 192.168.56.1:/var/www/vm /mnt/vagrant-vflsf_dz1yb40c5aje

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out

The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp 192.168.56.1:/var/www/vm /mnt/vagrant-vflsf_dz1yb40c5aje

Stdout from the command:      

Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out

 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::NFSMountFailed", "The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.\nVagrant assumes that this means the command failed!\n\nmount -o vers=3,udp 192.168.56.1:/var/www/vm /mnt/vagrant-vflsf_dz1yb40c5aje\n\nStdout from the command:\n\n\n\nStderr from the command:\n\nmount.nfs: Connection timed out\n"]
```

This is strange 'cause the IP pf the box is "192.168.56.102", not "192.168.56.1" and why "udp" ?
I've installed this package and plugin :

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
vagrant plugin install vagrant-bindfs
vagrant plugin repair
```

I'm on :

```
Vagrant 1.9.3
VirtualBox 5.0.32_Ubuntu r112930

Linux spectre 4.4.0-66-lowlatency #87-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 3 16:43:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

If I add --debug with Vagrant, the system ask me for root password, but, without the parameter, don't ask.

Any idea please ?

Thanks
Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

For me the culprit is **Cisco's AnyConnect VPN client**.
If you disconnect everything will work fine (No more Mounting NFS shared folders hangs).

Hoping to be useful.